# L5 Using Hashid in middleware returns null

Tags: laravel, hash, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using [hashid](https://jenssegers.com/64/easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5) to hash the id parameters in url.  I have it set up in my model to automatically hash the id.  This is working fine.  My problem is decoding the hash in a middleware returns null.  I'm not sure if this is a problem with my middleware or because of the hashing.

**Model:**

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'),10);
        return $hashids->encode($value);
    }
```

**Middleware:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HashIdsDecode
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->id); //Returns null on show method - example localhost:8000/invoices/afewRfshTl
        if($request->has('id'))
        {
            $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'),10);
            dd($hashids->decode($request->input('id')));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::resource('invoices','InvoiceController');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::find($id);
        return view('invoices.show', [
            'invoice' => $invoice,
            'page_title' => ' Invoices',
            'page_description' => 'View Invoice',
        ]);
    }
```

***NOTE:*** if I bypass the middleware and do it directly in my controller like this it works but it requires me to repeat myself over and over and probably not the best way to do it.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'),10);
        $invoiceId = $hashids->decode($id)[0];
        $invoice = Invoice::find($invoiceId);

        return view('invoices.show', [
            'invoice' => $invoice,
            'page_title' => ' Invoices',
            'page_description' => 'View Invoice',
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would be more inclined to write a model trait. You can then use the trait on only the models required, rather than assuming every ID argument in a request is a Hash ID.

E.g.

```
namespace App\Models\Traits;

use Hashids\Hashids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait HashedId
{
    public function scopeHashId(Builder $query, $id)
    {
        $hashIds = new Hashids(env('APP_KEY'), 10);
        $id = $hashIds->decode($id)[0];

        return $query->where('id', $id);
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you'd use the trait on your Invoice model (edit):

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use \App\Models\Traits\HashedId;

    // ...
}
```

And execute the following query in your controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::hashId($id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('invoices.show', [
        'invoice' => $invoice,
        'page_title' => ' Invoices',
        'page_description' => 'View Invoice',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not used traits before.  First question is can you show me an example of the model.  Second is I am implementing this after the fact so I would need to update a bunch of my controllers.  Is there not a way to just encode and decode the ID so I won't have the change my controllers to use `Model::hashId()`?

Comment: Finally got it working, this post helped: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-make-a-trait-in-laravel-53

Comment: @Derek I've updated my answer with an example of using the trait on a model

Comment: I have been using this method and it seems to have been working well except for use on manytomany relationships.  It looks like I have lost the ability to use things like `$model->relation` or `$model->relation->attach($relationid)`.  Is that true or how would I retain that functionality?

Comment: The trait shouldn't impact relationships. From the code you posted, it looks like you're still storing auto increment IDs for models and relationships. Is that correct? Can you post more code or link to a new question to show what's breaking and what your table schemas look like?

Comment: I just created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336740/l5-how-to-use-trait-that-hashes-id-but-keep-pivot-functionality

Comment: I've replied to your other question.