# L5 How to use trait that hashes id but keep pivot functionality

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I added hashes to my ID's using a trait.  However by doing that now I can no longer use attach() or relationships.

**For example this relationship does not work in my view anymore:**

```
@foreach ($invoice->items as $item)
   {{ $item->item }}
@endforeach
```

**Here is the trait that hashes the id for me**

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

use Hashids\Hashids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait HashedId
{


    /**
     * Get the user's id as hashids.
     *
     * @param  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'),10);
        return $hashids->encode($value);
    }

    public function scopeHashId(Builder $query, $id)
    {
        $hashIds = new Hashids(env('APP_KEY'), 10);
        $id = $hashIds->decode($id)[0];

        return $query->where('id', $id);
    }
}
```

**Invoice Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\HashedId;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use HipsterJazzbo\Landlord\BelongsToTenants;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use BelongsToTenants;
    use HashedId;
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'client_id',
        'invoice_number',
        'purchase_order',
        'invoice_note',
        'invoice_status',
        'invoice_total',
        'invoice_type',
        'sub_total',
        'balance_due',
        'due_date',
        'invoice_type',
        'user_id',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\LineItem', 'invoice_items', 'invoice_id', 'item_id');
    }

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }

}
```

I have tried doing this from a controller but it feels more like a hack than the right way to do it and I still lose the ability to use things like `$invoice->attach($lineItem)` or `$invoice->items`

```
//Currently I have to unhash the ids in order to save them as a pivot
$hashIds = new \Hashids\Hashids(env('APP_KEY'), 10);
$invoiceId = $hashIds->decode($request->invoice_id)[0];
$lineItemId = $hashIds->decode($request->item_id)[0];

//Should have been able to use $invoice->attach($lineItemId)
DB::table('invoice_items')->insert(
  ['invoice_id' => $invoiceId, 'item_id' => $lineItemId]
);
```

How can I continue to use `$invoice->attach($lineItem)` or `$invoice->items` from controllers while still using the trait that hashes my ids?

Comment: My goal was to have the ids hashed in the urls so they were not easily recognizable but the way I did it may have come at the cost of not being able to use manytomany relationships due to the id always being hashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've re-written the trait as follows (this assumes you're using PHP 5.6 or above):

```
<?php 

namespace App\Traits;

use Hashids\Hashids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait HashedId
{
    /**
     * Get model ID attribute encoded to hash ID.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHashIdAttribute()
    {
        $hashIds = new Hashids(env('APP_KEY'), 10);
        return $hashIds->encode($this->getKey());
    }

    /**
     * Restrict query scope to find model by encoded hash ID.
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  integer  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeHashId(Builder $query, $id)
    {
        $hashIds = new Hashids(env('APP_KEY'), 10);
        $id = $hashIds->decode($id)[0];

        return $query->where('id', $id);
    }

    /**
     * Restrict query scope to find models by encoded hash IDs.
     * 
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  array  $ids
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeHashIds(Builder $query, ...$ids)
    {
        $hashIds = new Hashids(env('APP_KEY'), 10);

        $ids = array_map(function ($id) use ($hashIds) {
            return $hashIds->decode($id)[0];
        }, $ids);

        return $query->whereIn('id', $ids);
    }
}
```

You may notice that I've renamed the accessor, `getIdAttribute()` to `getHashIdAttribute()`. You can therefore now get the hash ID of a model instance by calling `$model->hash_id` instead of `$model->id`.

This is where I think your problem was, because Laravel was expecting an integer key to be returned by `$model->id`, whereas it would have been getting the hash ID instead.

If after implementing the changes above you're still getting an error, can you show what the specific error is?

Comment: Rob, you have been a huge help so thank you for your responses.  I am still having a hell of a time using relationships and I have probably way over complicated this.  Can you show me a full example on how I can continue to use hashes in urls instead of ID's and how I would use things like `$model->relation->attach()`,  etc?  I am still learning laravel and hashing and traits are new concepts to me.

Comment: This paste should show everything I have going on: http://pastebin.com/MTVdWZ75  Just to reiterate, the hashed ids in the url work perfectly but when I go to use `attach()` in controller Im getting an integrity constraint violation exception on the database because it is trying to store the relation using the hashed ids instead of the real ones.

Comment: `FatalErrorException in HashedId.php line 44:
Cannot redeclare App\Traits\HashedId::scopeHashIds()`

Comment: Oops, my bad. I've renamed the first scope function to be `scopeHashId` and the second is `scopeHashIds`.

Comment: No errors but now (assuming I understand you correctly) if I use something like this in my view: `<a href="/invoices/{{ $invoice->hash_id }}">` then the url points to `/invoices` without an ID or hash

Comment: Ah, we renamed the `getHashIdAttribute` accessor, which means a `$value` will no longer be passed in, because it's not a defined attribute. I've updated the method to return `return $hashIds->encode($this->getKey());`

Comment: It's also worth looking into using named routes. Then you can use something like `<a href="{{ route('invoice.view', $invoice->hash_id) }}">` in your views. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Comment: Oh man its sooo close.  Everything is working except for one thing.  If I have a selectbox on my create invoice screen where user selects the client, the option value is hashed id.  When I go to save the invoice then it picks the wrong client. This is through a hasmany relation.  I checked and the hash is unique and if I decode the hash and `dd()` it shows the right ID but when saving it saves the invoice to the wrong client. I'm sure its something stupid, can we go to chat? Seems like BelongsToMany works now buy HasMany is off by a few?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136191/discussion-between-rob-and-derek).

Answer (score 1):

Just like you commented, you couldn't use attach because id is hashed cos of getIdAttribute. I would like to suggest you to use getOriginal().

For example,

```
$invoice->attach($lineItem->getOriginal()['id']);
```

I think that could be the only way to attach that.